# Hydration of form object that uses Doctrine ObjectSelect

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have an issue attempting to hydrate an object from a form, using ZF2.5 and Doctrine2.

I have a create form with a base fieldset configured for object type A. It is configured with a ClassMethods hydrator and initialised with a "new A()" object. By itself, this form works as expected - from the controller, upon validation, I can call $form->getData() to receive an object of type A which I then persist to the database.

Class A has a manyToOne relationship with Class B. I have attempted to add this relationship to the fieldset mentioned above as follows:

```
$this->add([
            'name' => 'class_A_field_name_for_class_B',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'options' => array(
                'object_manager'     => $this->entity_manager,
                'target_class'       => '\my\ClassB',
                'property' => 'name',
                'is_method' => true,
                'label' => 'Class B Selection'
            ),
            'attributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'required' => true
            ]
        ]);
```

Unfortunately, I get an error akin to this:

> Argument 1 passed to my\ClassA::setClassB()
>   must be an instance of my\ClassB,
>   string given, called in
>   /vagrant/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/Hydrator/ClassMethods.php
>   on line 220 and defined

I cannot work out what I am doing wrong. Any takers? I have tried changing the 'property' field to 'id' but all that does is try and call setClassB(3) instead (rather than hydrating the ClassB instance of id 3 and passing that to setClassB).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the select box when posted will be a string and the `ClassMethods` hydrator is using this value when calling `setClassB($string)`; which subsequently fails as the method expects an *object* of type `ClassB`.

In order for this relationship be hydrated, you will need to use the [Doctrine object hydrator, `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md). This hydrator will convert the relevant ids into new (or existing) `ClassB` instances.

```
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject;

$hydrator = new DoctrineObject($entityManager);
$objectA  = new ClassA();

$data = [
    'name'   => 'New class A',
    'classB' => 4  
);

$objectA = $hydrator->hydrate($data, $objectA);

echo $objectA->getName();    // 'new class A'
echo gettype($objectA->getClassB()); // object of type ClassB
```